# Rails PostgreSQL array can't iterate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, helper, production-environment

I wrote a helper method for my controller to iterate through an attribute, being represented as an array using PostgreSQL.

```
def format_cf array
  nums = ""
  array.each { |c| nums += "#{c}, " }
  unless nums.blank?
    nums.chop!.chop!
  end
  nums
end
```

This way, I don't get the messy `{}` chars in my view. I'm implementing an empty value for this attribute as the string '{}', meaning that's what I set the default value to in my migration. This hasn't been a problem for my development environment, as it interprets that as an empty array. However, now in production, this helper method is throwing an error saying

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for "{}":String)
```

Is my implementation wrong here, or can anyone think of some obscure setting I may have overlooked when comparing my development.rb and production.rb?

EDIT: 2013-04-11 9:00

I'm currently deploying using capistrano with unicorn and nginx

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you may have run into this bug as well, if you're using rails 4 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10432. Basically there's a bug in the Migrations system that turns `:string, array: true` into a normal `:string` directive.  The joys of using edge stuff huh.

Answer (score 0):

I gues you used taps to deploy tour database on heroku with

```
heroku db:push
```

Problem is that taps doesn't support Postgres array, and it ends up casting the column as a string. There are many workaround for that.
The one I used was to open a console on heroku

```
heroku run console
```

Then get a connection to the database

```
User.connection # or any of your models
```

And then execute raw sql with the `connection#execute` method in order to create a backup column, delete the current string column and recreate it as an array.

You'll probably find it more useful to use the [import/export](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) advised by heroku

And if you're not using heroku, then I' completely wrong, and I have no idea what your problem is :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using unicorn and nginx with capistrano for my deployment actually. Any knowledge on those in this context?

Comment: Sorry but no ... well it really looked like the issue I had with heroku though ! Good luck :)